# Blank / white page while there is an additional segment in the URL

Tags: ee2, url, freemember, white-screen-of-death

I am using freemember to customize the password change process of EE. It allow to change the default page used for resetting the password. This page is accessed by a link provided in a mail send to the user. This link is formatted as following.

`site/template_group/my_reset_password_page/reset_token`

The reset token look like this one : `exldroeqlik4`

I can access my custom reset page flawlessly if I don't add the reset token, so if the URL is the following : `site/template_group/my_reset_password_page`

Unfortunately, I can't access the page with the reset token. I am just stock in front of a white page.

From this [doc](http://myloanrefi.com/docs/general/urls.html#entries-and-other-things), I understand that these kind of URL are suppose to point to a specific entry. Here the entry channel is specified by the template_group segment of the URL and the entry is specified by the last segment.

In my case, the template_group segment does not refer to a channel.

What I am understanding is that since there is no channel EE can't find an entry and just show a white page.

Am I wrong?

How can I resolve this?

I am using :

- EE v2.6.1
- Freemember v2.3.2

### Edit 1 :

I don't think this will help a lot since the problem is on every page, but here is the code of my template.

```
<section class="main-wrapper">

    <div class="main-container container">

        <div class="span6">

            <h3>Reset password</h3>

            {exp:freemember:reset_password

            error_handling="inline" 
            error_delimiters="<span class='error'>|</span>"


            reset_code="{segment_2}"
            }


            <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="New password" value="">
            {error:password}

            <input type="password" name="password_confirm" placeholder="Confirmation password" value="">
            {error:password_confirm}

            <input type="submit" value="Change">


            {/exp:freemember:reset_password}

        </div>

    </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your template code, I'd wager that with a few tags we can sort it out.

```
{exp:channel: entries url_title="{segment_2}" limit="1" channel="ABC" }
```

This tells EE to look at segment 2 for the correct entry and will ignore segment 3 which it likely is now. You may also need to add `dynamic="no"` as well but see how you go with the extra tags to define the correct entry.

Comment: Unfortunately, my template does not need to access a channel entry. I am using freemember which use the reset password code provided as the last segment in the url.

Comment: Turn on debugging in the CP - white screens are usually suppressed php errors